# Segmentation fault when using fixed size array

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct{
    char name[100];
    long size;
    char mode[8];
    char uid[8];
    char ouid[8];
    char size1[12];
    char time[12];
    char checksum[8];
    char type[1];
    char linkname[100];
}HEADER;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= argc; i++) argv[0,1,2] are program name, c, tar output file
    {
        HEADER header;
        strcpy(header.name, argv[i]); // saving the name of the file
        FILE *fin = fopen(argv[i], "rb");
        if(fin == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "File not found.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        fseek(fin, 0L, SEEK_END);
        header.size = ftell(fin);
        printf("%s is %ld bytes long\n", header.name, header.size);
        fseek(fin, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        fclose(fin);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to store the number of bytes and the name of the files provided as command line arguments, but I'm getting a segmentation fault. I ran a debugger and strcpy is the problem, `name` has fixed size so I don't need to allocate memory. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `i <= argc` as the loop condition. The `argc` argument is the number of elements in the `argv` array, not the top valid index. Its semantics is very much similar to the string length returned by `strlen`.

But what's causing the crash is that the `argv` element at index `argc` (i.e. `argv[argc]`) is a *null pointer*. And you try to use this null pointer in several places (when `i` is equal to `argc`).

You need to use `i < argc` instead as the loop condition as well.

Answer (score 1):

`argc` has the number of parameters passed in the command line, +1 for the program name. This means that if the app is started with

```
app_name p1 p2
```

`argc` will be 3, but the index in the `argv` array is 0, 1 and 2. In the for loop, you are looping from 1 until `argc`, it should be from 1 to `argc-1`, because arrays in C starts from 0. If you replace `<=` with `<`, loop will iterate correctly.

```
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) argv[0,1,2] are program name, c, tar output file
    {
        HEADER header;
        strcpy(header.name, argv[i]); // saving the name of the file
```